# Incomplete "able to" in next sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider the following two sentences [(from this SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56093587/9609843):

> So the fact that you can now reference pygame.display is an accident
>   of implementation details. You may not be able to in future versions
>   (if the project no longer needs to import pygame.display to load
>   pygame.joystick, for example).

The sentence "You may not be able to in future versions" seems incomplete to me. I think it is missing something and "You may not be able to *do it* in future versions" will be more complete. So, my question, is the first form without *do it* correct and complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct and complete. You may omit the verb phrase when its meaning can be understood from the context. In linguistics, this phenomenon is known as ellipsis. 
In your example:

> So the fact that you can now reference pygame.display is an accident
>   of implementation details. You may not be able to [*reference
>   pygame.display*] in future versions.

One could also say

> You may not be able to *do that* in future versions.

Other examples of verb phrase ellipsis:

> A: Do you want me to go with you?
>
> B: Oh, you don’t have to [*go with me*].

or

> He says that I should become an astronaut, but I don’t want to
>   [*become an astronaut*].

Here’s a similar question — [Omitting verbs, is it correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317847/omitting-verbs-is-it-correct)